# Gitlab CI runner fails at docker-compose build with profiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

My idea is to have a single docker-compose file that I can configure with `--profile db_as_container` flag depending on whether I want to have cloud database (MongoDB atlas) or local database-as-container.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: '${APP_NAME}:${TAG:-latest}'
        build: .
        ports:
            - '${PORT}:${PORT}'

    mongo_db:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongo_db_container
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        profiles:
            - db_as_container
```

My docker compose up shell script (**dc-up.sh**) deduces whether my DB_CONNECTION_STRING is cloud type or local container type and calls appropriate up command.

```
TAG=${TAG} docker-compose --profile db_as_container up -d --build
```

vs.

```
TAG=${TAG} docker-compose up -d --build
```

And this **works** locally and does not complain about using profiles.

Problem is when my [Gitlab CI runner](https://pastebin.com/1p2NuJM3) runs my build script (**build-and-push.sh**):

```
TAG=${TAG} docker-compose build
```

It produces this error:

> The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> Unsupported config option for services.mongo_db: 'profiles'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the issue was not the version of the compose file specification, but rather docker-compose itself as i've found out [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/unsupported-config-option-for-services-profiles/103767)

> Support for service profiles was added in docker-compose version 1.28

Updating from 1.262 to **1.28.6** solved my issue.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I should have seen that your compose file was in version 3. Anyway, good job 

Answer (score 1):

Only [Docker Compose v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#profiles) has `profiles` option. I'm guessing your CI compose version is a lower one.

You will need to upgrade it to version 3.

Comment: When checking locally with docker-compose --version, it prints out: 
docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305. So my question would be, what is the difference between docker-compose CLI version and docker-compose file specification (which i have in my file set to 3)?